# iPhone Development -CGPoint & NSTimer help

Tags: iphone

i want to jump balls in a specific field in the view,
the problem is that i don't know how to define the positions of this field area and movement.
also 
here is the code that i use to move the ball in the entire view (the ball object is a uiimageview on the view).
thanks.

-(void) onTimer {
    ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x+pos.x,ball.center.y+pos.y);

```
if(ball.center.x > 320 || ball.center.x < 0)
    pos.x = -pos.x;
if(ball.center.y > 460 || ball.center.y < 0)
    pos.y = -pos.y;
```

}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    pos = CGPointMake(14.0,7.0);

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

}

Comment: You need to clarify your question and/or break it into parts. What is wrong with the code you have now i.e. what unexpected behavior do you see? e.g.Do the balls not move at all? Do they move but move incorrectly? Does the timer not call the `onTimer:` method?

Comment: in the code above it's work fine (the ball is moving in the entire  screen) but the problem is that i cant seem to define a small area in a specific location in the view instead of the 320\460. when i'm changing the values the ball just bounce in place or moving in a wrong location.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding 320 and 460, you can use the bounds of the view to get the are in which your balls should move.

Check out the `bounds` property of `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation ViewController {
    BOOL isPositiveXAxis;
    BOOL isPositiveYAxis;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //By default we are setting both BOOL value to YES because ballImage have (0,0) origin by default 
    isPositiveXAxis = YES;
    isPositiveYAxis = YES;
    imgBallView.layer.cornerRadius = imgBallView.frame.size.width/2;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(animateBall) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)animateBall {

        //getting current image transform, and we will modify it later in code
        CGAffineTransform transform = imgBallView.transform;


        //checking if ‘isPositiveXAxis is true and imgBallView xAxis have less value then view border
        if (isPositiveXAxis && imgBallView.frame.origin.x < self.view.frame.size.width - imgBallView.frame.size.width) {
            transform.tx++;
        }
        else {
            isPositiveXAxis = NO;

            if (transform.tx>0) {
                transform.tx--;
            }
            else {
                isPositiveXAxis = YES;
            }
        }

        //checking if ‘isPositiveYAxis is true and imgBallView yAxis have less value then view border
        if (isPositiveYAxis && imgBallView.frame.origin.y < self.view.frame.size.height - imgBallView.frame.size.height) {
            transform.ty++;
        }
        else {
            isPositiveYAxis = NO;

            if (transform.ty>0) {
                transform.ty--;
            }
            else {
                isPositiveYAxis = YES;
            }
        }

        //setting updated trasform to imgBallView it will look animated.
        imgBallView.transform =  transform;
}
```

The above code will generate the required pattern. It can be seen in the video: https://vid.me/G3zO,  which may help you understand it better